# Find initial velocity of ball??

Tags: vectors, kinematics

A basketball match is played on a level court.A player standing at origin throws a ball from height $2.1 m$ with velocity $V=ai+ bj+2.8k$. Another player standing at $10i +4j$ starts running with velocity $v=-3i -4j \space ms^{-1}$ towards the ball when it's thrown.He catches it $1.4 m$ above ground level. Assume acceleration is $-9.8k$

Find initial velocity and horizontal distance travelled by ball.

Comment: I found Vball=ai + bj+(2.8-9.8t)k so 
Position of ball,Rball=ati +btj+(2.1+2.8t-4.9t^2)k
The time of flight I found by equating the k component to 1.4. Then,2.1+2.8t-4.9t^2=1.4,so t=0.19s
Then how to find initial velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

First, find the time taken by the boy to reach $ai+bj$ from $10i+4j$ with a velocity $-3i-4j \space ms^{-1}$ using $v=\frac{s}{t}.$

Now, for the ball, you have the acceleration, displacement and time. So, use $s=ut\pm \frac{1}{2}at^2.$

Comment: Thanks i got a=55.63 and b=25.05.But how to get horizintal distance travelled by ball?Is it a×t or b×t?Or do i use pythagoras theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.  I think the solution you arrived at is wrong and the correct solution is given below  Good luck

[image]

[image]